# ayuda con formulario de envío con laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

es la primera vez que estoy tratando de implementar un muy simple y de prueba formulario de envíos con laravel, ayudado con un videotutorial pero hay algunas cosas que no me quedan claras, si alguien me pudiera corregir lo que según yo estoy configurando de la siguiente manera.

En esta parte configuro los datos del email desde donde envio, no?

- MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
- MAIL_HOST=smtpout.mi-pagina-web.com
- MAIL_PORT=80
- MAIL_USERNAME=info@mi-pagina-web.com
- MAIL_PASSWORD=*la clave de acceso por web mail*
- MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

En el controlador tengo

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\SendMail;

class SendEmailController extends Controller
{
    //
    function index()
    {
     return view('send_email');
    }

    function send(Request $request)
    {
     $this->validate($request,[
      'name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required|email',
      'message' => 'required'
     ]);

        $data = array(
            'name' => $request->name,
            'message' => $request->message

        );

        Mail::to('contactos@mi-pagina-web.com')->send(new SendMail($data));
        return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for contactUs');
    }
}
```

esto tengo en Mail:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('info@mi-pagina-web.com')->subject('New Customer Enquiry')->view('dynamic_email_template')->with('data', $this->data);
    }
}
```

y esto en la vista:

```html
<div class="container box">
      @if(count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
          <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
              <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
          </ul>
        </div>
      @endif


      @if($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
          <stron>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </div>
      @endif
      <form method ="POST" action="{{ url('sendemail/send') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
          <lable>Enter your name</lable>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"/ >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <lable>Enter your Email</lable>
          <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control"/ >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <lable>Enter your Message</lable>
          <textarea name="message" class=" form-control"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" class="btn btn-info"/ >
        </div>
      </form>
      
    </div>
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error al querer hacer el envío:

Connection could not be established with host smtpout.local-eventos-pachacamac.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. #0]